# Get each element from for each with Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I have this to fetch 3 values:

```
myRef.child("users").orderByKey()
                    .limitToLast(3)
                    .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
     Users us = snapshot.getValue(Users.class);
     if (firstvalue > second value) {
      //get third value 
     }
     Log.e("Datos: ", "" + us.getNumber());
    }
}
```

How it get each value from the for each loop inside dataSnapshot, lets say:

```
us.getNumber().get(0);
us.getNumber().get(1);
us.getNumber().get(2);
```

Thanks

Comment: Use an arraylist with datatype Users, then put it above your loop and then add Users into arraylist.

Comment: You must have firebase database URL then add .json preceded by firebase database URL like this `https://yourdatabaseurl.com/users.json`. Then you will get all response in JSON and would be able to get all the data easily. Let me know if you got an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see in your code, you are using a `limit(3)` call which will restrict the results in the `DataSnapshot` object to three. So to get those three users separately, add them to a `list` and use `list.get(position);` like this:

```
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<Users> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Users users = ds.getValue(Users.class);
            list.add(users);
        }

        Users firstUser = list.get(0);
        Users secondUser = list.get(1);
        Users thirdUser = list.get(2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to limit firebase database record. Where Football is the main root and then it has the following child's elements like 'Scores' and 'rank'. Either, You can do it like following or You can use Firebase database URL followed by .json will show all JSON data as response.

```
 DatabaseReference mDatabasePlayers = 
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Football");
 Query mDatabaseHighestPlayer = 
 mDatabasePlayers.child("Scores").orderByChild("rank").limitToLast(3);
 mDatabaseHighestPlayer.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
       for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
          String Key = childSnapshot.getKey();
          Toast.makeText(main.this,Key,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
    }
@Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
      throw databaseError.toException(); // don't swallow errors
    }
 });
```

It'll help you.